# Cannot read property 'spy' of undefined -mobx dev tools/ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

mobx developer tools on my chrome stopped working suddenly from today , I am getting the error like below

```
backend.js:4999 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'spy' of undefined
    at setup (VM14490 backend.js:4999)
    at VM14490 backend.js:4256
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VM14490 backend.js:4254
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at exports.default (VM14490 backend.js:4253)
    at handshake (VM14490 backend.js:4130)
    at helloListener (VM14490 backend.js:4171)
setup @ backend.js:4999
(anonymous) @ backend.js:4256
(anonymous) @ backend.js:4254
exports.default @ backend.js:4253
handshake @ backend.js:4130
helloListener @ backend.js:4171
postMessage (async)
listener @ contentScript.js:481
postMessage (async)
pingListener @ backend.js:4163
postMessage (async)
sendPing @ contentScript.js:462
338 @ contentScript.js:465
__webpack_require__ @ contentScript.js:20
(anonymous) @ contentScript.js:63
(anonymous) @ contentScript.js:66
```

I have no clue how I got this . I undo all the code changes I made today but still no luck. Life is too hard without debugger . Please let me know what is the fix for this?

I went through this https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-devtools/issues/64 thread as well .

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "..",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "dateformat": "^2.0.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.4",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mobx": "^3.3.1",
    "mobx-react": "^4.3.3",
    "mobx-store": "^3.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.2",
    "react-clickoutside": "^1.0.4",
    "react-date-picker": "^6.7.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.61.0",
    "react-dates": "^16.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-fileupload-progress": "^0.4.1",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.8.7",
    "react-image-slider": "^0.1.0",
    "react-modal": "^1.7.7",
    "react-moment": "^0.6.5",
    "react-portal-tooltip": "^1.1.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.16.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.3",
    "react-spinner": "^0.2.7",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.4.0",
    "reactable": "^0.14.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I also started seeing this error today.

Comment: In order to get an answer, you'll probably want to add your package.json to show what versions you're using and show some of your code.

Comment: The update from 20th march fixed this issue

Answer (score -1):

I just downgraded mobx chrome extension from here https://crx.dam.io/ext/pfgnfdagidkfgccljigdamigbcnndkod.html to solve this problem.